# Is "Do it faster than with any other product" correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I'd like to describe a procedure that take less time with a product A than any other product B or C....

Note that I don't want to say that product A is faster but just that doing something is faster with A than it is with any other product.

So is "Do it faster than with any other product" correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "is this grammatical?", then yes. A [google search for the exact string "faster than with"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22faster%20than%20with%22&oq=%22faster%20than%20with%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5754j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8)  yields ~44M results (including your own question in third place; go figure). The count is possibly inflated, and a significant percentage of the actual results are arguably spurious (e.g., second result is "faster than USB with Thunderbolt"), but you still get many results from high profile sources (e.g., tsa.com, apple.com, ncbi.nlm.nih.gov) that suggest that native speakers accept this particular construction.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. Do you still think it works without the "other", like "do it faster than with any app" ?. It seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: I would say you do need to have the "other" or your own app will be included in the statement, which would be paradoxical.

Comment: @aout - If you like my answer, please give me +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can say it like this: "Our product lets you do XXX/it faster than all the other products in the market."